# Фигурные скобки, передача массива в функцию, возвращение массива

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Я начинающий программист, не могу разобраться со значением {} фигурных скобок
[image: Это кусок кода, где есть вопрос]

Сама программа работает, но у преподавателя есть вопрос "Что означают фигурные скобки в данном контексте? Именно синтаксис и какую функцию несут?" 
Я не знаю что ответить, так как я знаю, что так многие пишут, но пояснить за работу не могу. 
Если что вся программа представлена ниже

[image: 1 Часть программы]

[image: 2 часть программы]

Comment: в данном конкретном случае, фигурные скобки означают создание вектора, функция depth_first_search последним элементов ожидает вектор интов, выражение { s } создает вектор из одного элемента https://habr.com/ru/post/330402/

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: дополню ответ `goldstar_labs` ...  теперь ваш вектор содержит один элемент, со значением `s` . Фигурные скобки создают список инициализации.

Answer (score 0):

По умолчанию обычные массивы локальной области видимости (например, объявленные внутри функции) остаются неинициализированными. Это означает, что ни один из его элементов не установлен на какое-либо конкретное значение; их содержимое не определено в точке, в которой объявлен массив.

Однако элементы массива при объявлении могут быть явно инициализированы до конкретных значений, заключив эти начальные значения в фигурные скобки {}. Например:

```
int foo [5] = { 16, 2, 77, 40, 12071 };
```

Соответственно конструкция

```
vector<int> foo={4};
```

инициализирует вектор из одного элемента, значение которого 4.

Вот пример использования при передаче параметра в функцию.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void func(int s, vector<int> vec){
 for (int i=0;i<vec.size();i++)
    cout << vec[i] << endl;

}

int main(){
    int s=3;
    func(s,{s});
    s=4;
    func(s,{s,s});


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: почему минус, что не так с ответом?

Answer (score 0):

> у преподавателя есть вопрос "Что означают фигурные скобки в данном контексте? Именно синтаксис и какую функцию несут?"

Если ответ "создают вектор из одного элемента" его не устроил, то это выглядит как "я не рассказывал про это на лекциях, поэтому не пишите так".

---

> какую функцию несут

Создают вектор из одного элемента `s`. Для этого вызывается конструктор `std::vector`, с параметром  `std::initializer_list` (9-ый конструктор [здесь](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)).

> синтаксис

Эти фигурные скобки в грамматике называются *braced-init-list*, почитать про их грамматику можно [тут](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#nt:braced-init-list).